# Virtual inheritance in a non Diamond Type

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have trouble understanding why virtual inheritance is useful in a situation where we do not meet a problem similar to the Diamond Problem when a class inherits from 2 classes derived from the same base class.

Could someone give me an example or explanation when it is still helpful (or needed even)?

Thanks:)

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a "diamond problem". The diamond is the *solution* to the not-having-a-diamond problem.

Comment: Did somebody say diamond?

Comment: @KerrekSB: ["**diamond problem**" is a common term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). you could have tried a [simple google search](https://www.google.no/search?q=%22diamond+problem%22), leading to wikipedia, blogs, SO questions, etc. the word "diamond" refers to the shape of a class inheritance diagram. the word "problem" refers, among other things, to the lack of such shape for the sub-object hierarchy, and how calls to member functions are resolved. In short, the OP's terminology is OK and understandable. And googlable.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual inheritance isn't really useful when there isn't a potential [diamond shape inheritance problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). That problem is what virtual inheritance is all about solving. At cost of weird object layout and having topmost base initialization invoked from most derived class.

The most common practical application of virtual inheritance is for interfaces.

With virtual inheritance you can use the Java technique of *inheriting in* an implementation.

---

In C++03 there were additional use cases for virtual inheritance, hacks based on the need for initializing the topmost class from the most derived one.

These use cases included:

- Making a class non-inheritable.
  Solved by `final` in C++11.
- Forcing use of a specific most-derived class (templated).
  In C++11 covariant functionality, such as a `clone` member function, can more easily be added via middle-man inheritance, with C++11 constructor argument forwarding.

Comment: @JBentley: inheriting in an implementation of an interface `I` means that you inherit twice from `I`, so there's the diamond pattern right there.

Answer (score 0):

"useful" is a subjective word.  It's useful enough to some people that it's a language feature in C++, but not enough to others that Java doesn't have it.  Interfaces are something similar but do not accomplish the same thing.

The common idiom is a mixin. You keep your regular class hierarchy, but you also inherit from another class that provides some additional (mixin?) functionality.  So, you don't use it so that your class can behave like its parent, but just for an implementation.

That seems like a useful thing to me.  But, that's subjective.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, in pre-c++11 era, `virtual` inheritance was useful to implement `final` like mechanism.

```
// template style may not work with clang++
template<class T> struct Wrap { typedef T type; };
template<class Derived> class Final { // no one should inherit `D` from hereon
  Final () {}  
  friend class Wrap<Derived>::type;
};

class D : virtual Final<D> {}; // `virtual` inheritance
class D2 : public D {};  // if anyone tries to still inherit `D`

int main () {
  D d;
  D2 d2;  // <--- an expected error occurs upon object declaration
}
```

Refer from Bjarne Stroustrup's page for simpler but limited way: 
[Can I stop people deriving from my class?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation)